# How to disable login url path in Laravel 5.5/5.6

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.5, laravel-5.6

I know how add custom login route in the `web.php` like:

```
Route::get('login-whatever', [
  'as' => 'login-whatever',
  'uses' => 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm'
]);
```

and add to `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`

```
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;

protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    return $request->expectsJson()
        ? response()->json(['message' => $exception->getMessage()], 401)
        : redirect()->guest(route('login-whatever'));
}
```

but it is still allows to login via `/login` route
[image]

Comment: looks like problem is bigger than I thought [github issue](https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/800)

Comment: Do you have `Route::auth()` anywhere in your routes file?

Comment: I tried this `Route::group(['prefix' => 'somepath'], function() {
    Route::auth();
});`but there is the same problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you catch the /login route and do a permanent redirect?

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], 'login', function(){
    return redirect('/');
});
```

or you can explicity state the controller and the function you want it to do.

```
Route::get('login', 'YourController@doYourFuntion')->name('name');
```

If this doens't work, give us the entirety of your routes code so we can help figure out the problem. Also edit the question with what you've tried so we don't spend time duplicating already tried methods. Thanks!

Comment: I tried. Even adding `Redirect 301 /login /404` to the `.htaccess` but it is redirects both routes unfortunately

Comment: I mean catching the route in laravel routes directly. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: I liked.. in fact, you just have to add it in the following way and it works:

    Auth::routes();
    Route::get('register', function () {
        return redirect('/');
    })->name('register');

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not 100% sure what you mean, but `Auth::routes()` is just a shortcut for the `auth()` function in `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php`. You can just comment those out if you don't want to see them. That probably isn't the best way to go about it though. You can just override those routes in `web.php`

Refer to this link for more info: [Overriding default auth routes](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/overriding-default-authroutes-in-laravel-53)

Answer (score 0):

The middleware classes in Laravel are the classes that are responsible for the authentication,

```
Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate
```

is the default authentication class. You should be able to override it easily.

Read from Laravel's documentation for more info https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication